# why a ioc framework for MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unity-container

After plenty of reading, I still don't understand Unity for MVC 3. 
Specific points

1. Why use it? I can create a controller that in its constructor, it takes a new EF context for testing.
2. How? I keep seeing bits are parts, but is there an end to end walk through on implementing Unity on MVC 3 (Live)? There seem to be plenty on Beta and RC, but the code always seems to have a problem on live frameworks.

Currently this is not impacting my unit testing, since my controllers have overloaded constructors, as does my EF context.

Comment: Not sure what your question here is - Why use IoC? Why Unity? Why with MVC? All of the above?

Comment: for loose couple and seperation of concerns, testing, and many other reasons.

Comment: DarthVader is exactly right on the nose with the Why. As for Unity, I was hoping to stick with the MS Patterns and Practices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a small project, you may not benefit from IoC.
Lifetime management if a plus for me. I don't have to dispose a repository (or service layer) in every controller. It thins out my code and creates the object for me. In addition, I know I have a clean separation in case I ever need to change things. It almost forces me to. I use for example IRepository that is backed by entity framework. For testing I use a fake IRepository implementation. So sure, I could manually create it in my application but this leads to some bad practices in larger projects and I lose the benefits of having the interface.

I have a basic demo for a super short talk I did recently on this for (15 minutes) mvc and unity  for dependency injection using the unity.mvc3 nuget package:
http://completedevelopment.blogspot.com/2011/12/using-dependency-injection-with-mvc.html

Btw. Dependency Injection in .Net - best book on the subject without a doubt.

Answer (score 0):

It's very useful for wiring up all your dependencies, handling life cycle of your objects, error handling, transaction handling, testing purposes and ...

All of above point are advantages of using an IoC framework, but I strongly recommend using [Ninject](http://ninject.org). it has a very friendly DSL for binding modules, has out of box library and extensions for ASP.NET MVC and is an open source lightweight DI framework.

It has also many extensions.

Comment: Yes, I find Ninject to be much easier to implement than Unity.  But it's really just personal preference, they all do the same things.